# how to instantiate recursive foreign key in django?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

```
class Notebook(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    father = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How to use it?

```
n1=Notebook(title='a', father='???')  
n2=Notebook(title='b', father=n1)
```

how to set the value for father attribute of n1?

Comment: have you tried n1=Notebook(title='a', father='self')?

Comment: yes, it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
class Notebook(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    father = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # change is here <<


parent = Notebook.objects.create(title="some title")
child = Notebook.objects.create(title='child title', parent=parent)
```

Comment: Am sorry i made an error, i wanted to say the person ( Lexinton Ave) who ask for help did not not mark the answer, the answer is so perfect and deserves a thumbs up, he was suppose to mark it